# Where can I download kernel 5.4.0-42-generic?

Tags: kernel

I want to install 5.4.0-42-generic in Ubuntu 20.10 following these instructions https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/12/install-linux-kernel-5-10-ubuntu-linux-mint but can't find it in the list [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline). Where is it?

Comment: The blog installs kernel 5.10

Comment: @yang mandi Yes but I've used the same instructions to install 5.11. Didn't solve my issues. 5.4.0-42 works good in my 20.04 so I wanted to try that.

Comment: You risk creating problems come *release-upgrade* time, so I'd consider migrating back to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (and using the GA kernel). Don't forget *groovy* isn't a LTS release, so needing to *release-upgrade* isn't that far away....

Comment: I also think installing an older kernel is NOT a good idea - what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve ? Maybe there are a better way than tinkering with old kernels and the problems that they potentially gives.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thanks. Graphics. I'll probably stick with 20.04 then.

Comment: @SorenA Graphics on a Dell i5 with UHD Graphics 620. Was bad before in 20.04. Turing off swap helped. 5.4.0-42 works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the files for kernel 5.4.0-42 can be found here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-5.4/ - but you will probably have to manually resolve dependencies yourself.